# Accessing the value of a key in a nested JSON converted to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I wish to access the value of `'elevation'` i.e. `1608.637939453125` and store it into the variable `'g'`. Below is the code

```
    import requests, json
r = requests.get(api link)

r= json.loads(r.text)

g=r['results']['elevation']
```

the above code returns this error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here's the dictionary data

```
  {

   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.7391536,
            "lng" : -104.9847034
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `results` is a list of dictionaries, not another dictionary.  So you have to access the value of `elevation` like this:

```
g = x['results'][0]['elevation']
```

If results had more entries in the list, which is common, you can loop through them like this:

```
for result in x['results']:
  print(result)
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. Could you explain why i need to add [0]?

Comment: Sure, results is a list, so to access elements of the list, you need to use the list index (which is an integer).  Lists in python are zero indexed, so you use `x['results'][0]` to access the first result in the list